# How can I find and delete a file if I don't know where it is?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the file `text.txt` somewhere on my computer, which is running Windows. I don't know exactly where it is, but I know it's there. Is there any command I can use to find and delete this file?

Comment: If you don't know where it is, how do you know that it exists?

Comment: it is like you searching for a file you don't know where is it

Comment: In UNIX, you'd use the `find` command, but I think you are using Windows.

Comment: yes batch file.bat it's on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows 2003 or later, you can use the `where` command.

If you have a general idea of where the file is, you can pass it to `where` as part of the `/r` option, otherwise, you can look in the entire drive (although be warned, it's really, really slow if your hard drive is big).

From there, you can pass the results of the search to a `for /f` loop and delete anything `where` finds.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('where /r C:\ text.txt') do del "%%A"
```

From `where /?`:

```
WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...

Description:
    Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
    By default, the search is done along the current directory and
    in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

Parameter List:
    /R       Recursively searches and displays the files that match the
             given pattern starting from the specified directory.

    /Q       Returns only the exit code, without displaying the list
             of matched files. (Quiet mode)

    /F       Displays the matched filename in double quotes.

    /T       Displays the file size, last modified date and time for all
             matched files.

    pattern  Specifies the search pattern for the files to match.
             Wildcards * and ? can be used in the pattern. The
             "$env:pattern" and "path:pattern" formats can also be
             specified, where "env" is an environment variable and
             the search is done in the specified paths of the "env"
             environment variable. These formats should not be used
             with /R. The search is also done by appending the
             extensions of the PATHEXT variable to the pattern.

     /?      Displays this help message.

  NOTE: The tool returns an error level of 0 if the search is
        successful, of 1 if the search is unsuccessful and
        of 2 for failures or errors.

Examples:
    WHERE /?
    WHERE myfilename1 myfile????.*
    WHERE $windir:*.*
    WHERE /R c:\windows *.exe *.dll *.bat
    WHERE /Q ??.???
    WHERE "c:\windows;c:\windows\system32:*.dll"
    WHERE /F /T *.dll
```

[ss64 Page](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Comment: ok it works but it cannot delete the file if it is on a folder with spaces like new folder or something

Comment: @Potter - I've added quotes to the del command to handle spaces in paths.

Comment: Thank you it works so the right command is going to be "for /f "delims=" %%A in ('where /r C:\ text.txt') do del "%%A""
and if i want to change the pattern i will replace the c:\text.txt to D:\text.txt

Comment: @Potter - there's a space between `C:` and `text.txt`; it's saying "search everywhere in C: for a file with the exact name text.txt". But yes, if you want to search D: instead, replace `C:` with `D:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
del /s /a /f c:\myfile.txt
```

`/s` says to search hard drive starting a `c:\` to find the file and delete it. `/a` says find hidden files as well. `/f` says delete read only files as well (normally `del` won't).

Comment: Yes, that is the right method to use. Command __del__ has built-in the feature for searching recursively for one or more files to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In linux (or windows with cygwin) you can use [locate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate). This will find every `file.txt` on the drive and prompt for each file if you want to remove it.

```
for path in $(locate /file.txt); do rm -i "$path"; done
```

Comment: The comments mention that this is for Windows.

Comment: Good thing locate is available in cygwin as well.